# Read WKT geometry using JTS 1.13 in Java

Tags: javascript, openlayers, java, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I want to create a shapefile from coordinates, in the client side I take the coordinates of a polygon by OpenLayers, it sends it to a Java class, in this class I read the geometry of the polygon, but when the geometry is read, the method shows this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

I'm using this code:

Here I take the geometry of the vector:

```
 .....
    {
        var featureGeom = [];
        var arreglo = [];
        var arreglo2 = [];

        var controlador = aplicacion.getController("ControlResultados");        
        var vectorSeleccion = controlador.buscarcapa('capaSeleccion').getSource().getFeatures();

        for (var x = 0; x < vectorSeleccion.length; x++) {
            featureGeom.push(vectorSeleccion[x].getGeometry().getCoordinates());
            for (var y = 0; y < featureGeom[x][0].length; y++) {
                arreglo.push(featureGeom[x][0][y]);
            }
        }

        for (var z = 0; z < arreglo.length; z++) {
            arreglo2.push(arreglo[z][0]+" "+arreglo[z][1]);
        }

        var nombreArchivo = "archivoSHPResultado";
        var parametros = {
                archivoPersistencia : nombreArchivo,
                geomPolygon : "POLYGON(("+arreglo2.toString()+"))",
                nombreArchivo: 'CapaSHPResultado'
        };
        this.descargaArchivoSHP(parametros);
    },
    descargaArchivoSHP: function(contenido){
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : "ServletShape",
            method : 'POST',
            params : contenido,
            success : function( respuesta ) {
                var rutaActual = location.href.split("//");
                var rutaActualPartes = rutaActual[1].split("/");
                var nuevaRuta = rutaActual[0] + "//" + rutaActualPartes[0] + "/" + rutaActualPartes[1] + "/" + respuesta.responseText;

                window.open(nuevaRuta);

                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'WARN',
                    msg: 'OK',
                    buttonText: {
                        yes: 'OK',
                    }
                });
            },
            failure : function() {

                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'WARN',
                    msg: 'FAIL',
                    buttonText: {
                        yes: 'OK',
                    }
                });
            }
        }); 
  }
  ......
```

Here's the Java class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.DefaultTransaction;
import org.geotools.data.Transaction;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStoreFactory;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureStore;
import org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;

import utilidades.utilidadesGeometriaGeotools;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

public class BBShape {

private static final int BUFFER = 4096;
private String rutaPersistencia = null; 
private String nombreArchivoZip = null;
private String nombreXlsSalida = null;

public String getRutaPersistencia() {
 return rutaPersistencia;
}

public void setRutaPersistencia(String rutaPersistencia) {
  this.rutaPersistencia = rutaPersistencia;
}

public String getNombreArchivoZip() {
  return nombreArchivoZip;
}

public void setNombreArchivoZip(String nombreArchivoZip) {
this.nombreArchivoZip = nombreArchivoZip;
}

public void Exportar(String nombreShape, String tipoShape, String geomShape, String separador){

try {

    String pathArchivo = rutaPersistencia + nombreShape + ".shp";

    SimpleFeatureType featureType =  DataUtilities.createType( tipoShape,  "location:" + tipoShape + ":srid=4326," + "number:Integer");

    DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal",featureType);

    String[] geomArray = geomShape.split(separador);

    for (int i = 0; i < geomArray.length; i++) {
        Geometry geometria = utilidadesGeometriaGeotools.WKTgeometriaLectura(geomArray[i]);
        featureCollection.add( SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( featureType, new Object[]{ geometria, 2}, null) );
    }

    File file = new File(pathArchivo);  

    ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

    Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    params.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());
    params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

    ShapefileDataStore newDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);
    newDataStore.createSchema(featureType);
    newDataStore.forceSchemaCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);

    Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

    String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

    if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
        SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

        featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
        try {
            featureStore.addFeatures(featureCollection);
            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception problem) {
            problem.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();

        } finally {
            transaction.close();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(typeName + " No se peude acceder");
    }

} catch (Exception e1) {

}   
}

public void deleteFolderContent(File folder){
  File[] files = folder.listFiles();
  if(files!=null)
    for(File f: files)
        if(f.isDirectory()) deleteFolderContent(f);
        else f.delete();
}

public String zipDirectorio() {

String pathCarpeta= rutaPersistencia;
String pathArchivo = pathCarpeta + nombreArchivoZip + ".zip";

File d = new File(pathCarpeta);
if (!d.isDirectory())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(pathCarpeta + " no es un directorio." );
String[] entries = d.list();

byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER];
int bytesRead;

try {
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathArchivo));

    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        File f = new File(d, entries[i]);

        if (f.isDirectory())
            continue; 

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entries[i]);
        out.putNextEntry(entry);

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        in.close();
    }
    out.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

nombreXlsSalida = this.getNombreArchivoZip() + ".zip";

return (nombreXlsSalida);
}

public String  exportarOpcionesSHP(String pathLogico, String ruta, String geomPolygon, String nombre){

this.setRutaPersistencia(ruta);

String strPathFile = "";
File f=new File(ruta);
f.mkdir();

if(f.exists()){
    this.deleteFolderContent(f);

    if (!geomPolygon.equals("")) this.Exportar("poligonos", "Polygon", geomPolygon, "%,");
}

this.setNombreArchivoZip(nombre);
strPathFile = this.zipDirectorio();

strPathFile = pathLogico + strPathFile;
return strPathFile;
}   
}
```

Here read the geometry

```
package utilidades;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTWriter;

public class utilidadesGeometriaGeotools {

static public String WKTgeometria(Geometry geom){

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
WKTWriter wktWriter = new WKTWriter(2);

try {
    wktWriter.write( geom, writer );
} catch (IOException e) {
}
String wkt = writer.toString();
return wkt;
}
static public Geometry WKTgeometriaLectura(String geom){
Geometry geometria = null;        
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);

try {
    geometria = (Geometry) reader.read(geom);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return geometria;
}

 static public LineString  construirLinea (Double xIni,Double yIni,Double xFin,Double yFin ){    
return  (LineString) WKTgeometriaLectura("LINESTRING("+xIni+" "+yIni+","+ xFin+" "+yFin+")");
}

static public Geometry transformacion(Geometry geom,String sistemaOrigen,String sistemaDestino ){

Geometry salidaGeometry = null; 
try {               
    CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode(sistemaOrigen);//CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode(sistemaDestino); //CRS.decode("EPSG:3116");    
    MathTransform   transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, false);
    salidaGeometry = JTS.transform( geom, transform);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return salidaGeometry;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the polygon by adding the start point to the end of the list of points that you build the WKT with. So change it to:

```
    for (var z = 0; z < arreglo.length; z++) {
        arreglo2.push(arreglo[z][0]+" "+arreglo[z][1]);
    }
    arreglo2.push(arreglo[0][0]+" "+arreglo[0][1]);
```

But I'm pretty sure you can use the [OpenLayers WKT](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/WKT-js.html) functionality

```
    WKT.write(layer.selectedFeatures[0]);
```

to do the same thing more easily.

Or if you are using many polygons, I would go straight to GeoJSON up and use the GeoTools GeoJSON Datastore to read it into a feature collection and then write it out as a Shapefile.